# Copy link from cell content

Tags: excel, search, hyperlink, ms-office

I have an excel file with Text in each cell (A:A) and I would like to use a formula to search in the cell and copy a link from the cell content to (B:B).

example:

--------A    -------------- B

text text link text ----  link

Is it possible to use a function for this?
btw. the link always begins with http://bit.ly/

Comment: Your example is confusing... I'm not quite sure what you need.

Comment: @JTFRage but why, it's easy to understand. In column A he has some text with or without a link in B he wants to copy the link from A if there is one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in B1 and drag down in column B

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("http://bit.ly/",A1),(FIND(" ",A1,FIND("http://bit.ly/",A1)+1)-(FIND("http://bit.ly/",A1)))),"")
```

here is a spreadsheet that's working : http://wikisend.com/download/310302/CopyLink.xlsx

Here is an update to do it in case you have up to 3 links, with helper columns:
http://wikisend.com/download/122554/CopyLink_2.xlsx

Comment: Thank Julien, I have tried to use this formula but it says that it contains an error and i can not figure out what it is..

Comment: Works fine. I'll edit my answer to include a spreadsheet. Could be because you don't have the same separator "," or different language for functions. Opening a spreadsheet will convert it for you. Let me know if that doesn't solve it.

Comment: Great it seems to work in your file :) Thanks!
But there is one more thing, some of the cells include 2 or 3 links that also start with http://bit.ly/..
is there a chance to filter them also out to the next column (C:C) (D:D) ?

Comment: Yes. The same way in the above formula at some point in `FIND(" ",A1,FIND("http://bit.ly/",A1)+1)` I'm nesting a `FIND` inside another `FIND` to find the position of the second space. So it's definitely possible but starting to be a bit tedious. In that case I suggest using helper columns or it'll start looking awful. Another way is to use a Regular Expression in VBA which will find submatches.

Comment: I edited my above post to include this link: http://wikisend.com/download/122554/CopyLink_2.xlsx which does it with helper columns.
Please upvote the post if it does the job